# What's the difference between terracotta-hibernate-cache and Ehcache Distributed with Terracotta?

Tags: hibernate, ehcache, second-level-cache, terracotta

Is there a difference between using Ehcache as Hibernate's second-level cache provider and distributing it with Terracotta, and using `terracotta-hibernate-cache` and `terracotta-hibernate-agent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is the latter is deprecated and you should use the former.
terracotta-hiberante-cache & others predate the Ehcache acquisition. In the meantime ehcache (clustered with terracotta or not) has had much investment done in and provide you with better results...

Comment: Excellent, thanks! That's what I guessed, but wasn't quite sure. I'd been using the Ehcache/Terracotta docs, and only stumbled across terracotta-hibernate-cache *after* implementing it!